# Pre-Existing Code or Template for Intranet User Provisioning (i.e. role assignment) in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

When you create a new MVC project in Visual Studio, you get an AccountController that supports user self-registration and self-help changing passwords.  This is great as a basic first step for a public internet site.  But for an intranet site where an admin is responsible for creating users and assign them roles, is there any equivalent pre-existing template to start from?

To clarify, I am looking for a template that continues to use basic auth and that continues to use the ASP.Net membership and role services, as does the internet template, but provides UIs for user and role management that are intended for use by an administrator.  The site is going to be on the internet but is not going to be "public" per se.  There will be one or more sys-admin accounts that will have the ability to provision  other users.  The site will hosted by a yet-to-be-selected hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called the Intranet Application.  I know, who would think an Intranet application was an Intranet application?

MVC3 has 3 templates, Empty, Internet Application and Intranet Application.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that template is of no use to us and indeed would be a step in the wrong direction.  It contains no functionality for managing users or roles but simply relies on windows authentication, presumably delegating the whole user provisioning issue to Active Directory.  To clarify, I am looking for a template that continues to use basic auth and that continues to use the ASP.Net membership and role services, as does the internet template, but provides UIs for user and role management that are intended for use by an administrator.

Comment: @KennethBaltrinic -1 for asking a question without specifying your requirements and expecting us to be mind readers. There was nothing in your question that stated you wanted to continue using forms authentication, or that you wanted a UI to maintain users.  Further, there was nothing in your question that stated the Intranet template was insufficient.  Intranet sites are almost always AD based, which is why this template exists.  No, there is no template that includes user management.  FYI, you should edit your question, not add additional requirements in comments to answers.

Comment: Took your advice and added the clarification of requirements to the original question.